# How to limit queryselector to a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, queryselector

I have a react component with a list of child-components. In the child-component I want to target a specific DOM element e.g., to change the color in its `ComponentDidMount` method. How would I do this?

**Parent component**

```
export class ListComponent extends Component<...> {
    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <div>
                <ListItemComponent key="123"/>
                <ListItemComponent key="456"/>
                <ListItemComponent key="789"/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child component**

```
export class ListComponent extends Component<...> {
    componentDidMount(): void {
//      const elementToChange = document.queryselector(".toTarget");  // Only works for the first element as it only targets the first on the page
        const elementToChange = THISREACTCOMPONENT.queryselector(".toTarget");
        elementToChange.style.backgroundColor = "123123";
    }

    render(): ReactNode {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="toTarget">
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So, the question is, what should be instead of THISREACTCOMPONENT? How to target an element exclusively within the react component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a react `ref`.
[Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) were created so you won't have to use queryselector, as interacting directly with the dom may lead to react bugs further down the line.

```
  export  class ListComponent extends Component<...> { {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef(); // Get a reference to a DOM element
      }
    componentDidMount(): void {
        const elementToChange = this.myref.current;
        elementToChange.style.backgroundColor = "123123";
    }
      render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="toTarget"  ref={this.myRef}> // binds this element to the this.myref variable
            </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Looks interesting! When I try it, though, I get an error `Property 'querySelector' does not exist on type 'RefObject<unknown>'`. I guess I need to change unknown to something else, but what?

Comment: updated answer, added 'current' No need to use querySelector, this.myref.current is the element

Answer (score 1):

**You could use [Document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all matching elements**

`document.querySelectorAll` returns an array of matching element.

Then you would do it like so:

```
componentDidMount(): void {
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".toTarget");
  elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "123123";
  });
}
```

Comment: So you would set the colors in the componentDidMount method in the parent component? That is indeed a solution. Still I would like to contain the logic to the child component if possible. Nevertheless, I will keep this solution as an option if no other solution comes up! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer. But I wonder why you need to set it in your `componentDidMount` but not directly define it in JSX?

Comment: "123123" should instead be a valid colour though, just to remind you.

Comment: I want the color of an element to be changed to the same color of one of its child elements. These child elements are passed as a ReactFragment as a prop, though, and I don't really have access to it (afaik) until they are rendered

Comment: Oh, I see, try my answer, see if it works for you